# jQuery form - multiple routes

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form split into 2 steps. Step 2 has 2 different fieldsets, depending on an option selected in the first step. So you have step 1, then step 2a and 2b. I can't figure out how to pull the value from a dropdown and use that to progress to either step 2a or 2b. Here is my HTML:

```
<fieldset class="step1">
    <label>Options</label>
    <select class="mySelect">
        <option value="steb2a">Step 2a</option>
        <option value="steb2b">Step 2b</option>
    </select>
    <a class="nextStep">Next</a>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="step2a">
    <label>Question 2a</label>
    <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="step2b">
    <label>Question 2b</label>
    <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
```

And here's my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".step2a").addClass("hidePanel");
    $(".step2b").addClass("hidePanel");
    $(".nextStep").click(function () {
        $(".step1").addClass("hidePanel");
        $('.mySelect').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'step2a') {
                $(".step2a").removeClass("hidePanel").addClass("showPanel");
            } else if ($(this).val() == 'step2b') {
                $(".step2b").removeClass("hidePanel").addClass("showPanel");
            }
        });         
    });
});
```

This looks logical to me, but it doesn't work, it hides the first fieldset OK but doesn't add the 'showPanel' class to the next fieldset. Have I made a simple mistake, or am I approaching this completely wrong? Any help appreciated. I've created a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LTMzF/

Answer (score 2):

Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/fyU6N/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. Yours appears to be a nice easy way of skipping between 3 parts, but I need mine to skip from, say, part 1 to part 3, missing part 2, depending on the option chosen in the dropdown. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly it. Is there a simple way of changing it from a jump menu to needing to press 'next' to progress to the chosen step? As there will be multiple choices on that step. Sorry for all of the questions.